# HIghcharts Heatmap as a week timeline

Tags: highcharts, d3heatmap

I came across this highcharts heatmap and I am trying to convert if to a map with weekdays in X axis. This is what my data looks like:

`Sun,18,35036
Fri,18,36644
Sun,16,25922
Fri,16,29407
Fri,15,22161
Fri,14,15978
Fri,13,11793
Fri,12,8362
Fri,11,5597
Fri,10,3945
Fri,6,7955`

Here I have `weekday, hour, value`. How can I convert the monthly heatmap to weekly heatmap? 
[JSFiddle Monthly Heatmap](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap-canvas/)

Comment: Sort your data by weekdays and use category axis (it is default type) instead of datetime - adjust the rest options like axis min/max etc. http://jsfiddle.net/63awoadw/ Available options can be found in official API http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis

Comment: @morganfree: I tried adding categories, but data is not getting grouped. here is the updated snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/63awoadw/4/

thank you

Comment: Set data.firstRowAsNames to false and xAxis.uniqueNames to true - http://jsfiddle.net/63awoadw/5/